# Make android animation SMOOTH

Tags: android, android-studio, animation

I'm making a splash activity with some animations.

A background image(640x425, 58.4KB, JPG) is being slightly zoomed during 1500ms,

and another image(300x300, 20.3KB, PNG),  is fading in during 750ms after waiting 750ms.

The first time you run, the animation is smooth.

But, If you repeat the execution, the animation is laggy.

My phone is Samsung GALAXY Note 5.

Here is my code.

**AndroidMenifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

**SplashAcivity.java**

```
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String TAG = SplashActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Animation zoom_in;
    private Animation fade_in;

    private ImageView splashBackground;
    private ImageView CI;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        zoom_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_in);
        fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);

        splashBackground = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashBackground);
        CI = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.CI);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        splashBackground.startAnimation(zoom_in);
        CI.startAnimation(fade_in);
    }
}
```

**fade_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <alpha
        android:startOffset="750"
        android:duration="750"
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"/>
</set>
```

**zoom_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <scale
        android:duration="@integer/splash_animation_duration"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toXScale="1.05"
        android:toYScale="1.05" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

make your duration is smaller than 750. Just make it 300.